# Has anyone found this error with Safari before?

Tags: safari

I've been contacted because [this site](http://en.onviure.ad/) crashes Safari everytime you click on any select in the search box (you might have to scroll a bit).

There's no error in the Developer Tools console and Safari throws an error everytime it crashes. I posted a sample [here](https://pastebin.com/hEPBVqMq). A small extract of the error so it lets me post the pastebin link:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
Crashing on exception: -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7767687437
```

I've tried everything:

- Changing the option values (to only numerics, to not contain negative numbers, to not have duplicates...)
- Removing all non-bootstrap CSS code affecting the selects.
- Removing all JS code affecting the form.
- Removing all JS code on the site.
- Disabling JS in Safari, clearing the caches, blocking cookies...
- Installing Midori, another Webkit-based browser, to see if it also crashed. It didn't, so it seems a Safari-specific bug.
- Installing Safari Technology Preview to check if it is fixed. Nope.

Nothing worked. It crashes everytime you click on a select.

Has anyone found this problem before? Any idea on how to fix it? To me it clearly seems like a Safari bug. After two days trying to make it work, I'm seriously thinking about telling my client that Safari has a problem and he should contact Apple Support.

Answer (score 1):

After some time-wasting testing, I nailed it down to the webfont used in the site, [Comfortaa](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comfortaa). Apparently using this font with `font-weight: 300` (loaded from Google fonts) in a `select` will make Safari crash when you click on it.

Yet another proof that Safari is the new IE.